# AWS Secret Manager - 403 response on GetSecret

Tags: asp.net-core, aws-sdk, aws-secrets-manager

I'm working on an ASP.NET Core project that will be deployed to AWS. Recently the client came back and requested to pull a few values from AWS SecretsManager. I'm using the permissions inherited from the IAM Role associated to the EC2 instance that the service is deployed to.

In production use this service will be hosted by the client themselves on their own AWS account.

When I deploy to my own test AWS account the process works just fine but when the client deploys to their own AWS account they are getting a 403 Forbidden response on the call to get the secret value. They have the secret and permissions policy set up like I do but still the 403 error.

```
AmazonSecretsManagerClient client = new AmazonSecretsManagerClient();
var secretRequest = new GetSecretValueRequest
{
    SecretId = "MySecretName"
};

// FAILS HERE
GetSecretValueResponse secretResponse = await client.GetSecretValueAsync(secretRequest);
```

It is a HttpRequestException with a message of "Response status code does not indicate success: 403 (Forbidden)."

My question isn't really a coding issue since this does work on my test AWS account. This seems like it must be an environment issue with the client's AWS account.

My experience with AWS is very limited so I have no idea what would be causing this.

Comment: It would appear that the credentials they are using are not permitted to make that API call. You should determine where they are running this code, what credentials it is using, and then check whether those credentials have the necessary permission. (Or, it might be a networking issue and they aren't even reaching AWS.)

Comment: There aren't any specific credentials. Determining permissions is done by the permissions policy of the IAM Role associated with the EC2 instance that is running the service. This setup works just fine on my own AWS environment.

Comment: Are they trying to access a secret in your account, or in their account? They can test things by using the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) to call the secrets manager with `aws secretsmanager get-secret-value` command. That will give better information to figure out what might be happening.

Comment: The secret they will be accessing will be in their own account.

Comment: You will need to debug it on their system. Start by trying with the AWS CLI (as per comment above), then try your code. You might need to look at the permissions on the Role assigned to the EC2 instance.

Answer (score 1):

Is the customer trying to fetch the exact same secret you are using in your account? This would require using a custom CMK and adding a resource policy granting access as described in the [AWS docs](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-access-secrets-across-aws-accounts-by-attaching-resource-based-policies/).

Comment: The secret they will be accessing will be in their own account.